# Is there multiple range command for Vim or Vi?

Tags: vim, command, vi, macvim

I want to do something in range [a, b] and [c, d], or much more range.

For example, I want to replace "abc" with "def" in lines between 1~10, and lines between 50~60.
I will do the two edit operation below:

#### (1)       :1,10s/abc/def/g

#### (2)       :50,60s/abc/def/g

Can I do this in just one command?

Answer (score 8):

You can't have a non-contiguous range but it's easy enough to repeat the same substitution on another range:

```
:1,10s/abc/def/g|50,60&&
```

See `:help :&`.

Comment: May also want to look into using `:g` if there is a pattern that can be found on each line. See `:h :g`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the [multiselect.vim](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=953) plugin.

```
:1,10MSAdd
:50,60MSAdd
:MSExecCmd s/abc/def/g
```